# Running multiple mysite

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-service, mysites

I know this question has been asked before, and i have read many blogs about my question but i cant get a clear answer, everyone is saying different things.

We have one farm with one web-application (webapp 1) and a my-site web-application which is working heavily with their own managed metadata. ( Usergroup 1 )

Now we need to add another web-application (webapp 2) with it's own mysite. They must be isolated from each other. ( Usergroup 2 )

We don't want to "destroy" webapp 1's managed metadata by adding more users through their user profile services connection, which would add irrelevant terms to their managed metadata. I was thinking of setting up another user profile service for webapp 2, but I've read that you can only have 1 user profile service sync per application server.

Is there anyway around this or is my only choice to add another application server? Can i make multiple user profile connections and still keep them separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like time to test it out in a virtual environment. I cannot answer for you as I have not done this, BUT, you should be able to do this.

1. Create a Second User Profile Service Application
2. If you are not going to share user Metadata, you either need to try to change the metadata bindings on the default User Properties or create a second Managed Metadata Service and include it in the Service application proxy group with your new UPA.
3. Configure Synchronization (be sure you can do this after #2) Perform the synchronization and see that your MMS data is properly populated.

Are you going to include these users in People Search? You will have to plan for that too.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time! I've created another UPS and assigned it to the second proxy group, where the second Managed Metadata Service and the second Search Service Application is included. So the next step is just to run the User Profile Synch Service for the newly created UPS? According to this thread it wont be possible to do what i would like to? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42146/multiple-my-site-hosts

Comment: I should add that we are using Active Directory import.

Comment: You just need a second server to run the second instance of the User Profile Sync.

Comment: Could you give me some guidance in what the difference it would make to run the second User Profile Sync on the application server? The first UPS sync is running on the WFE right now.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but aside from management and performance it should be fine. You have to be sure to chose the right UPA when you start the sync service on each server.

Comment: After some more reading, is it really necessary to use SharePoint Profile Synchronization when i'm using AD import?  The way i see it now is that if i you AD import i don't need to use User Profile Sync? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219646.aspx

Comment: It's usually one or the other not both. Depends on your business need. Do you need Export and the additional capability of FIM?

Comment: Then i stick with the AD import, all i really needed was to add the users.. so i guess i don't need to use the user profiles sync at all? Thanks again.